# Provide jvm args file or JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS to Tomcat installed as Windows Service

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services

I'm looking for a way to provide a jvm args file to Tomcat when it is installed as a Windows Service.

I know that I can do this when running java from the cmd line
`java '@C:/path/to/jvmArgs' -jar test.jar`

I also know that I can add it as the `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` env variable and it is picked up by `java.exe` when run through `catalina.bat` etc.

**However**, when installing Tomcat and running it as a windows service nothing works. I even tried adding `++Environment JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS='@C:/jvmArgs'` to the service installation command but it still didn't pick them up. Maybe I'm doing it wrong but is this the right way?